# One of my methods uses a variable that is returned in another method. I cannot get the second method to print or calculate

Tags: java, methods

A painting company has determined that for every 115 square feet of wall space, one gallon
of paint and eight hours of labor will be required. The company charges $18.00 per hour
for labor. Write a program that allows the user to enter the number of rooms to be painted
and the price of the paint per gallon. It should also ask for the square feet of wall space in
each room. The program should have methods that return the following data:
• The number of gallons of paint required
• The hours of labor required
• The cost of the paint
• The labor charges
• The total cost of the paint job
Then it should display the data on the screen.

I have not worked on the labor part of this problem yet, but i can not get costOfPaint() to print because of the paintNeeded variable.

I have tried writing the statement in the costOfPaint method in to the main method and it works. But that does not help as I need the method to do this. I know my problem has to do with the paintNeeded variable, I am just unsure of how to fix this.

public class Main{

```
public static double paintRequired(double totalSquareFeet){

    double paintNeeded = totalSquareFeet / 115;
    return paintNeeded;

                                                          }

public static double costOfPaint(double paintNeeded, double costOfPaint){
    double paintCost = paintNeeded * costOfPaint;
    return paintCost;
                                                    }


public static void main(String[] args){
    double costOfPaint = 0;
    int totalSquareFeet = 0;
    double paintNeeded = 0;

    Scanner getUserInput = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.println("what is the cost of the paint per gallon");
        costOfPaint = getUserInput.nextDouble();
    System.out.println("How many rooms do you need painted");
        int rooms = getUserInput.nextInt();
            for(int i = 1; i <= rooms; i++){
                System.out.println("how many square feet are in room:" + i);
                int roomSquareFeet = getUserInput.nextInt();
                totalSquareFeet = roomSquareFeet + totalSquareFeet;
                                           }

    System.out.println("the amount of paint needed:" + paintRequired(totalSquareFeet) + "gallons");
    System.out.println("the cost of the paint will be: " + costOfPaint(paintNeeded, costOfPaint));

}
```

}

For my costOfPaint i keep getting 0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't change `paintNeeded`. It's always `0`.

```
paintNeeded = paintRequired(totalSquareFeet);

System.out.println("the amount of paint needed: " + paintNeeded + " gallons");
System.out.println("the cost of the paint will be: " + costOfPaint(paintNeeded, costOfPaint));
```